# UISegmentedControl reset programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl that loads other UIViewController's. When going back, I want to see it unselected. I tried setting selectedSegmentIndex=-1 and selected=NO, but they didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to show some code, otherwise we don't know what is really happening.

Comment: Setting the `selectedSegmentIndex` to `-1` should be working. Are you sure your outlets are connected? Is your `UISegmentedControl` instance nil?

Comment: @MarkAdams you're absolutely right! Turns out my outlet is mixed up with another controller somehow. That fixed the problem. Thanks sosborn as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.mySegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

Answer (score 1):

During setup, try this:

```
segmControl.momentary = YES;
```